# Making a wildcard integer in an if statement for any number on and between 1 and 50

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I change the following:

```
if key == (2, *) and (1, 1) in previous:
```

To make the `*` turn into any number between 1 and 50 (including 1 and 50)

I've tried the following but it didn't work...

```
if key == (2, range(1, 50)) and (1, 1) in previous:
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Without more context, it is difficult to understand what you are asking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare by element:

```
if (key[0] == 2) and (1 <= key[1] <= 50) and ((1, 1) in previous):
```

Or, without the between comparison:

```
if (key[0] == 2 and key[1] >= 1 and key[1] <= 50) and ((1,1) in previous):
```

Comment: How can I change this so : `if key == (*, * | "") and (1, 1) in previous:` **note 2 "wildcards" and 1 or blank **

Comment: `if ((key[0]>=1 and key[1]<=50) or key is None)...`? sorry for the answer, but I find it hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: use `` symbols for code comments :P also no problem, all three of your answers are goood enough. I forgot that they were a list item. `key[0]` and `key[1]`

Answer (score 5):

The following will be true if both a) the iterable `previous` contains a tuple equal to `(1,1)`, and b) the tuple `key` is equal to the any of `(2,1)`, `(2,2)`, ... `(2,50)`.

```
if key in ((2,i) for i in range(1,51)) and (1,1) in previous:
```

If the number of elements in the range is very large (1000's or 100,000's), you might prefer:

```
if len(key)==2 and key[0]==2 and 1 <= key[1] <= 50 and (1,1) in previous:
```

Comment: How can I change this so : `if key == (*, * | "") and (1, 1) in previous:` **note 2 "wildcards" and 1 or blank **

Answer (score 4):

Create a custom object whose `__eq__` performs the check:

```
class AnyOf(object):
    def __init__(self, valid):
        self.valid = set(valid)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other in self.valid

between_1_and_50 = AnyOf(xrange(1, 51))

if key == (2, between_1_and_50):
    # do something...
```

You could also extend that using `functools.total_ordering` to support a greater range of comparisons if required.